# How to install Wkhtmltopdf in Amazon Linux 2023?

Tags: ruby, wkhtmltopdf, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2, amazon-linux-2023

I am upgrading my servers to Amazon Linux 2023 from AL2. My application needs wkhtmltopdf and now while trying to install it I see that is not officially released on my specific OS version. I have already tried to install the version for AL2 but after installing all dependencies it still missing libpng.

I tried downloading the .rpm file from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html under the AL2 aarch64 and ran `sudo yum install wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.amazonlinux2.aarch64.rpm`. It seems to install correctly but executing a sample `wkhtmltopdf google.com google.pdf` fails. Any ideas on how to build wkhtmltopdf in Amazon Linux 2023?

On a side question. I see the Github repositories associated to this [library are Archived](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf), should I consider migrating my application's PDF generation to a different lib?

```
[ec2-user@backoffice ~]$ sudo yum install wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.amazonlinux2.aarch64.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 1:02:21 ago on Mon Nov 20 20:13:06 2023.
Dependencies resolved.
===========================================================================================================================================
 Package                                  Architecture           Version                                 Repository                   Size
===========================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 wkhtmltox                                aarch64                1:0.12.6-1.amazonlinux2                 @commandline                 13 M
Installing dependencies:
 cairo                                    aarch64                1.17.6-2.amzn2023.0.1                   amazonlinux                 669 k
 fontconfig                               aarch64                2.13.94-2.amzn2023.0.2                  amazonlinux                 278 k
 fonts-filesystem                         noarch                 1:2.0.5-12.amzn2023.0.2                 amazonlinux                 9.5 k
 freetype                                 aarch64                2.13.0-2.amzn2023.0.1                   amazonlinux                 412 k
 google-noto-fonts-common                 noarch                 20201206-2.amzn2023.0.2                 amazonlinux                  15 k
 google-noto-sans-vf-fonts                noarch                 20201206-2.amzn2023.0.2                 amazonlinux                 492 k
 graphite2                                aarch64                1.3.14-7.amzn2023.0.2                   amazonlinux                  93 k
 harfbuzz                                 aarch64                7.0.0-2.amzn2023.0.1                    amazonlinux                 843 k
 langpacks-core-font-en                   noarch                 3.0-21.amzn2023.0.4                     amazonlinux                  10 k
 libX11                                   aarch64                1.7.2-3.amzn2023.0.4                    amazonlinux                 648 k
 libX11-common                            noarch                 1.7.2-3.amzn2023.0.4                    amazonlinux                 152 k
 libXau                                   aarch64                1.0.9-6.amzn2023.0.2                    amazonlinux                  32 k
 libXext                                  aarch64                1.3.4-6.amzn2023.0.2                    amazonlinux                  40 k
 libXrender                               aarch64                0.9.10-14.amzn2023.0.2                  amazonlinux                  27 k
 libfontenc                               aarch64                1.1.3-15.amzn2023.0.2                   amazonlinux                  31 k
 libjpeg-turbo                            aarch64                2.1.4-2.amzn2023.0.5                    amazonlinux                 191 k
 libpng                                   aarch64                2:1.6.37-10.amzn2023.0.6                amazonlinux                 121 k
 libxcb                                   aarch64                1.13.1-7.amzn2023.0.2                   amazonlinux                 231 k
 mkfontscale                              aarch64                1.2.1-2.amzn2023.0.3                    amazonlinux                  33 k
 pixman                                   aarch64                0.40.0-3.amzn2023.0.3                   amazonlinux                 194 k
 ttmkfdir                                 aarch64                3.0.9-63.amzn2023.0.2                   amazonlinux                  51 k
 xml-common                               noarch                 0.6.3-56.amzn2023.0.2                   amazonlinux                  32 k
 xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi                     noarch                 7.5-31.amzn2023.0.2                     amazonlinux                 2.7 M
 xorg-x11-fonts-Type1                     noarch                 7.5-31.amzn2023.0.2                     amazonlinux                 500 k

Transaction Summary
===========================================================================================================================================
Install  25 Packages
```

Trying:

```
[ec2-user@backoffice ~]$ wkhtmltopdf
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.6/bin/wkhtmltopdf_centos_6_i386: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.6/bin/wkhtmltopdf_centos_6_i386: cannot execute binary file
[ec2-user@backoffice ~]$ wkhtmltoimage
wkhtmltoimage: error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[ec2-user@backoffice ~]$ which wkhtmltoimage
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
[ec2-user@backoffice ~]$ cd /usr/local/bin/
[ec2-user@backoffice bin]$ ls
wkhtmltoimage  wkhtmltopdf
[ec2-user@backoffice bin]$ ./wkhtmltopdf
./wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: wkhtmltopdf was not updated for many years (and was only barely kept alive for several years before that) and has no maintainer anymore. See https://wkhtmltopdf.org/status.html for details.

Comment: @HolgerJust eew, thanks for pointing that out, probably i better recommend a lib change

Answer (score 5):

Not sure whether you are looking for a solution still, but leaving this here to help someone else potentially.

This solution is not intended for aarch64, but could likely be modified to work on aarch64. `wkhtmltox` is dependant on specific versions of `openssl` and `libpng` which are not the versions installed by default on the Amazon Linux 2 machines. In order to make this work on aarch64 the `openssl`, `libpng` and `wkhtmltox` would have to be swapped for aarch64 versions:

```
commands:
    01_install_dependencies: 
      command: yum install --assumeyes zlib fontconfig freetype libX11 libXext libXrender xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
    02_install_libpng15: 
      command: yum localinstall -y https://repo.almalinux.org/almalinux/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/libpng15-1.5.30-7.el8.x86_64.rpm
    03_install_libssl10: 
      command: yum localinstall -y https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/compat-openssl10-1.0.2o-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
    04_install_wkhtmltox:
      command: yum localinstall -y https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.amazonlinux2.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: This worked fine for me. This was placed in my file .ebextensions/wkhtmltopdf.config. Platform version on Elastic Beanstalk: Python 3.11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023/4.0.7

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker, the linux generic available on version 12.3 is working for amd64:

```bash
RUN mkdir wkhtmltopdf && \
    wget -O wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz "https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz" && \
    tar -xJf "wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz" -C wkhtmltopdf --strip-components=1 && \
    mv wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin && \
    rm "wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz" -r wkhtmltopdf
```

If you're using locally a mac M1 that will not work because of the processor architecture, so I use this for development:

```bash
RUN mkdir wkhtmltopdf && \
    wget -O /tmp/wkhtmltox.rpm https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6.1-2/wkhtmltox-0.12.6.1-2.almalinux9.aarch64.rpm && \
    yum localinstall -y /tmp/wkhtmltox.rpm
```

I discovered this by trial and error, so hope it helps.